# MAUI Navigation Toolbar disappears after changing Main Page

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

In short, I want to make an app which has a login page and, once login is successful, the user is sent to the main page. However, the user MUST NOT be able to go back to the login page, so I can't use the Navigation Stack for this.

I then tried using the `Application.Current.MainPage` property to move to the main page without using the Navigation Stack but then the navigation toolbar disappears, and I'll need it to have the app's menu button there. I even manually set `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"` in the `.xaml` file and added a `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);` line in the page's constructor - both to no avail.

After looking online, I remembered that the `Navigation.NavigationStack` could be cleared back in the Xamarin days by using `Navigation.RemovePage(page)` for each page in the stack, so I went back to using the navigation stack. Oddly enough, however, the app's root page is `null` in the stack and can't ever be removed that way.

Then I tried removing the page itself once the Login button is pressed with `Navigation.RemovePage(this)` - once again, to no avail.

Finally, I tried using Shell navigation instead with `Shell.Current.GotoAsync("//" + nameof(MainPage))`, which throws me a `System.ArgumentException: 'unable to figure out route for: //MainPage (Parameter 'uri')'`. I figured it was a routing error so I added `Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));` prior to the `GotoAsync` call but now it throws me the following:

`System.Exception: 'Global routes currently cannot be the only page on the stack, so absolute routing to global routes is not supported. For now, just navigate to: MainPage'`

So, even though the question's title refers only to the toolbar disappearing when setting the `Application.Current.MainPage` property, I'll also use this opportunity to ask how to properly clear the Navigation Stack so that the back button disappears, thus disallowing the user from going back to the Login page?

NOTE: This was tested on an Android Virtual Device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navigate to the `Login` page

```
MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

then when after login

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

or

```
App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
```